# Eclipse Helios for Java EE hangs on Ubuntu 32-bit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I'm using Eclipse Helios for Java EE on Ubuntu 32-bit DE. Eclipse hangs for about 20 seconds when the content assist pops up (usually on large classes such as JFrame). I'm using it with GWT plugin and WindowBuilder.

So far I've tried changing to default settings, working on a new workspace, increasing the memory, nothing worked. BTW, I'm using Sun JDK.

Can this be a plugin-related issue? Is it a common problem?

Comment: Did you try those settings in your `eclipse.ini`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it takes some time to build the internal indexes.  The usual reason for this taking long is insufficient physical memory available to Eclipse.

What is your machine configuration?

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 2.65 GHz, 3Gb DDR2, 200 Gb Hdd.